# spring.jackson.deserialization.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS: true not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

Used spring.jackson.deserialization.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS: true to preserve trailing zeros, but unfortunately did not work. I have also tried

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.indentOutput(true);
    builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
    return builder;
}
```

This also did not work, `indentOutput(true)` is works fine, but `featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS)` does not work

Comment: Can you provide a [complete example](/help/mcve) of your problem? It's very hard to know what the problem might be based on a small snippet of code.

Comment: The problem is of striping trailing zeros e.g. actual value 15.5000, desired value 15.5000, output value 15.5. By using USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS we can overcome this problem. To do this we have to add a bean (or a property in application.yml) like above, but the USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS not working, while other works fine like WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, INDENT_OUTPUT.